# KeyError: None when making forecasting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keras, tf.keras

I have the following code to make DNN forecasting

```
forecast = []
for time in range(len(series) - window_size):
  forecast.append(model.predict(series[time:time + window_size][np.newaxis]))

forecast = forecast[split_time-window_size:]
results = np.array(forecast)[:, 0, 0]


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

plot_series(time_valid, x_valid)
plot_series(time_valid, results)
```

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: -9223372036854775808

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

KeyError: NaT

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
5 frames
KeyError: NaT

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    625             return Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    626         except KeyError as err:
--> 627             raise KeyError(orig_key) from err
    628 
    629     def _maybe_cast_for_get_loc(self, key) -> Timestamp:

KeyError: None
```

My time variable is dates

```
series=df['Close']
time=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
time
```

Thanks

Comment: So you have a DataFrame with among others a column containing closing prices and the timestamp is in the index?

Comment: Instead of `series[time:time + window_size][np.newaxis]`, perhaps try `series[time:time + window_size].to_numpy()[np.newaxis]` i.e., go to numpy array from the series and then add a new axis.